# How to build JSON-LD for graphical data

Tags: javascript, json, frontend, seo, json-ld

Below Image represents graph generated by chart.js, this graph has to be represented on a web page, to represent this graph we need to add json-ld schema for json embedding.

[image: Graphical representation of job count for each education level in an organization]

questions:-

1. What @type we need to describe this graph into json-ld?.
2. How can we edit this schema according to this graph?.

*Sample schema*

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Table",
  "about": "list of presidents"
}
</script>
```